# dirent.h not returning all items

Tags: c++, networking, drive, subdirectory, dirent.h

I am currently developing C++ applications using Visual Studio 9 and some QT tools. My dirent version is 1.13. I can't remember if I got this version together with my VS installation or I replaced it with the one I have in my downloads folder.

Anyway, My application is using the code below to get user input of a selected mapped network drive that I will scan for subdirectories. The approach below does not return all items though. There are only 112 subdirectories at the moment but the loop only gets 101 items including the "." and ".." items. Anyone here who has encountered this before or has a suggested remedy?

Thank you.

```
DIR *dir1;
struct dirent *ent1;
QByteArray ba;
QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,
tr("Find Files"), QDir::currentPath());

QDirIterator dirIt(directory,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

ba = directory.toLocal8Bit();

if ((dir1 = opendir (ba.data())) != NULL) 
{
   ctr = 0;
   while ((ent1 = readdir (dir1)) != NULL) 
   {
      ctr++;
      qDebug()<<ctr<<". "<<ent1->d_name;
   }
}
```

Comment: The 11 missing directories hidden perchance?

Comment: Hi Jite, the directories are not hidden.

Comment: `readdir` does not read just 'subdirectories', it reads files as well. (That's not the problem, but you might want to add some logic to test for a directory.) Can you look up one of the "not found" directories and check its properties?

Comment: Hi Jongware, I had some filtering for the subdirectories I needed depending on d_type and d_name but I decided to remove it just to see what the current code can successfully read in the selected drive. I have this little check within the while loop

'code'
if (ent1->d_type == DT_DIR)
'code'

When I right click the missing folders and select properties, the attributes checked are only "Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)" and "Archive" - same as the subdirectories that are found.

Comment: Hi guys,

I'm still encountering this problem. To be able to accomplish the task, I temporarily abandoned using dirent for this particular requirement. When I get some spare time I'll try to do this again the "dirent" way. If I will be able to solve this I'll post here again. 

To accomplish the task, I did the following steps:

1. Get the list of subdirectories in the selected directory/drive using DIR
2. save the output of step 1 into a text file
3. read the contents of the text file and continue with the processing
4. watch as the user approves or disapproves of the tool.

Thanks!